# Confused with a basic math problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

For what values of $x$, does the relation $\left|x + \dfrac{1}{x}\right| \le 4$ hold?

I can see $x\ne0$.

Comment: Hint:  Just go case by case.  First suppose that $0≤x+\frac 1x<4$  That's really just a quadratic equation.  Now suppose that $0≤-x-\frac 1x<4$.  In each case you need to confirm that your solution satisfy both of the required inequalities

Comment: As @lulu said, go case by case. Also, there is probably a cap in the size of $x$.

Comment: And when in doubt, don't start with the algebra. Draw a rough graph first: in this case, of $x+\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the absolute value, if $x$ is a solution, so is $-x$, and we can temporarily restrict to the positive $x$.

We rewrite the equation as

$$x+\frac1x<4$$ or
$$x^2-4x+1<0.$$

The trinomial is negative between its two roots, i.e. in $(2-\sqrt3,2+\sqrt3)$, and the complete solution set is

$$(-2-\sqrt3,-2+\sqrt3)\cup(2-\sqrt3,2+\sqrt3).$$

Answer (score 1):

$|x + \frac{1}{x}| < 4 \iff |\frac{x^2+1}{x}|<4 \iff |x^2+1|<4|x| \text{  (because |x| positive)} \iff x^2+1 < 4|x|$

Consider the **case** **$x>0$** :
We have $x^2+1 < 4x \iff x^2-4x+1<0$
You need to solve this quadratic inequality, in order to find all the $x$ such as the relation is verified.
The roots are $2 \pm \sqrt{3}$, and the dominant coefficient is positive so the relation is true for $x\in (2 - \sqrt{3},2 + \sqrt{3}) \cap \mathbb{R}^+=(2 - \sqrt{3},2 + \sqrt{3})$.

Finally do the same for the **second case** $x<0$. The union of the solutions for the two cases is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=\lvert x\rvert$. You get the inequation
$$u^2+1 <4u\iff (u-2)^2-3<0\iff 2-\sqrt 3<u<2+\sqrt3. $$
As all numbers above are positive, we have
$$2-\sqrt 3<\lvert x\rvert<2+\sqrt3\iff\begin{cases}
\;\;2-\sqrt 3<x<2+\sqrt3\\\text{or}\\-2-\sqrt 3<x<-2+\sqrt3.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Still another downvote without an explanation!